# Rake aborted due to Migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was changing the name of my previous followers model. I decided to go back to it's original name but was having errors. I decided to use the Drop_table method to solve the issue but further issue pursist. I deleted any file related to followers and did rake db:schema:load which resulted in no errors. But whenever I try to do

```
rails g model Follower follower_id:integer followed_id:integer
```

and edit it to

```
def change
    create_table :followers do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :followers, :follower_id
    add_index :followers, :leader_id
    add_index :followers, [:follower_id, :leader_id], unique: true
  end
```

Then I execute `rake db:migrate` and I get the following. Anyone has an idea how I'll be able to fix this issue without having to start from the beginning? any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
== 20150910203914 CreateFollowers: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:followers)
   -> 0.0011s
-- add_index(:followers, :follower_id)
   -> 0.0004s
-- add_index(:followers, :leader_id)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table followers has no column named leader_id: CREATE  INDEX "index_followers_on_leader_id" ON "followers" ("leader_id")/Users/Steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you don't have a column named `leader_id`. You should change your migration to:

```
def change
  create_table :followers do |t|
    t.integer :follower_id
    t.integer :leader_id
    t.timestamps
  end
  add_index :followers, :follower_id
  add_index :followers, :leader_id
  add_index :followers, [:follower_id, :leader_id], unique: true
end
```

or rather change `leader_id` by `followed_id`.

You should also check the `references` modifier in activerecord migrations ([source](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)).

Comment: @jihonora Thank you!! I can't believe I'm making such a silly and obvious mistake. I will be more careful on how I'm writing my code from now on. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @StevenOssorio that's alright, happens all the time. Nice dog :)

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have a column `leader_id`.  You can see that because you are creating the table in the migration, and only specifying 3 columns, not of which is `leader_id`.  But you are trying to add an index using that column, which is what generates the error.  If you don't want that column anymore, you need to change the index.  If you do want it, then do as jihonora suggests.